# Android sending data to php function

Tags: php, android, database

I havnt been able to find a guide on how to submit data to a database from android through php.

say for instance i have the following site:

```
function insert($var1) {
    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO report (name) VALUES ('$var1')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database;
        $msg = "Message received.";
    } else {
        $msg = "Not received.";
    }

    return ($msg);
}

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
   $name = $_POST['name']);
   insert($name);   
} else {
   echo "No input.";
}
```

How would i call this from my Android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) but you do need a web-server for it.

Request mechanism Android App ----> webserver ------> database (mysql)

Respond mechanism Android App <---- webserver <------ database (mysql)

Android App will use [JSON](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) or [other](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) to get the data and display it

**PHP Code**

```
   <?php

        $con=mysql_connect("host","username");
        if(!$con)
        {
        die("Could Not Connect".mysql_error());
        }

        $db="CREATE DATABASE login";
        mysql_query($db,$con);

        mysql_select_db("login",$con);

        $tab="CREATE TABLE info(FirstName varchar(20),LastName varchar(20))";
        mysql_query($tab,$con);

        $user_fname=$_POST['fn'];
        $user_lname=$_POST['ln'];

        $row= mysql_query("INSERT INTO info (FirstName,LastName)  VALUES('$user_fname',   '$user_lname')");
        if ($row) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
        echo $row;
        }
        mysql_close($con);

     ?>
```

**Sending the Data (Android)**

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:4001/file.php");


        List<NameValuePair> pair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fn",fname));
        pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ln",lname));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: In the tutorial i can only seem to find the retrieve of data not the actual sending? i want to send data to my php code that then sends it to my database